# Encoding of GrailsElements in JavaScript Method

Tags: javascript, grails, encoding

Good evening

I'm building an userinterface for 1-n relations in grails with javascript.
It should be possible to add and remove items in the userinterface. that
works just fine, but I have an issue filling a dropdownbox in the 
generated html via javascript.
The javascript method looks like this:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
                                            var childCount = ${subList?.size()} +0;

                                            function addChild() {
                                                var htmlId = "book" + childCount;
                                                var deleteIcon = "${resource(dir:'images/skin', file:'database_delete.png')}";
                                                var templateHtml = "<div id='ba" + htmlId + "'><div id='ba" + htmlId + "' name='" + htmlId + "'>\n";
                                                templateHtml += "<input type='text' id='" + childCount + "' name='ba" + childCount + "' />\n";
                                                templateHtml += "${select(name: 'huhu', from: SubCategory.list())}";
                                                templateHtml += "<span onClick='$(\"#" + htmlId + "\").remove();'><img src='" + deleteIcon + "' /></span>\n";
                                                templateHtml += "</div>\n";
                                                $("#childList").append(templateHtml);
                                                childCount++;
                                            }
                                        </script>
```

line:
`templateHtml += "${select(name: 'huhu', from: SubCategory.list())}";`
will be transformed into:
`templateHtml += "&lt;select name=&quot;huhu&quot; id=&quot;huhu&quot; &gt;
&lt;option value=&quot;Sub Category&quot; &gt;Kat1&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option value=&quot;Digital&quot; &gt;Kat2&lt;/option&gt;`

and obviously that doens't work. I don't know how to solve this. most likely
it's simple. all the encodings in the IDE are set to UTF8, as are
for the file.
Any ideas?

used software: grails 2.5.1, java 1.7, intellij IDEA 14.1.4

Comment: can you post your config.groovy file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good way to use generator in string for js. Because enter wouldn't be in one line, so you will be have problems with multylines in js.. i.e.
If it will be work right your output will be:

```
 templateHtml += "<select name="huhu" id="huhu">
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>";
```

As you can see it wouldn't be work. So the best way for you it use g:each tag:

```
templateHtml += "<select name='huhu' id='huhu'>";
<g:each in="${SubCategory.list()}" var="category">
templateHtml += '<option value="${category.id}">${category.name}</option>';
</g:each>
templateHtml += "</select>";
```

Hope it will be helpful